# OnTriggerExit2D called when still colliding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2D top down game. I would like the player to walk onto the platform and have it move beneath them to get over obstacles.

To do this I've created a platform that goes back and forth between positions. If the player collides with the platform they have their `transform.parent` set to the platforms `transform`.

This works and the player moves with the platform. The problem is that once the platform moves past where it's original `BoxCollider2D` was, it calls `OnTriggerExit2D. This is called even though the player is still colliding with the platform. The only difference is that it is now a child of it.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Vector2> positions;
    public float speed = 1;
    public bool forward = true;
    public float stopTime = 1;

    private Vector2 nextPosition;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    private int currentPosition = 0;
    private float waitTime = 0;

    private GameObject collidingObject;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        nextPosition = positions[0];
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    /**
     * Code to move the platform back and forth between positions
     */
    void Update()
    {
        if (waitTime <= 0)
        {
            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, nextPosition) > 0)
            {
                float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextPosition, step);
            }
            else
            {
                if (forward)
                {
                    if (currentPosition < positions.Count - 1)
                    {
                        currentPosition++;
                        nextPosition = positions[currentPosition];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        waitTime = stopTime;
                        forward = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (currentPosition > 0)
                    {
                        currentPosition--;
                        nextPosition = positions[currentPosition];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        waitTime = stopTime;
                        forward = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag.Equals("Player"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Connecting");
            collidingObject = other.gameObject;
            collidingObject.transform.parent = transform;
        }

    }

    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag.Equals("Player") && collidingObject != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Disconnecting");
            collidingObject.transform.parent = null;
            collidingObject = null;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems as though it is detecting the collision with where the platform used to be and isn't updating the new position of the rigidbody.

What could be causing this?

**Update**
I've tried using this in the `Player` component.

```
private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag.Equals("Moving Platform"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Connecting");
        transform.parent = other.transform;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Disconnecting");
        transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

It is successfully adding the moving platform as it's child but it still ends up setting the parent to null when it is still colliding.

Comment: See [Unity Answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/167404/rigidbody-on-a-platform.html) about moving rigidbodies on moving platforms

Comment: I've gone through the answers and have gotten nowhere. I've updated my question.

Comment: Instead of setting the platform's transform position, which can lead to rigidbody synchronization issues, use [`rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html): `rigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nextPosition, step));`. You should also consider moving this code to `FixedUpdate`, because it moves rigidbodies around.

Comment: Are you setting the parent in two locations now? I suggest using `Debug.Break()` in your code where your platform's collider exit code is. Also, you're using `OnTrigger`, you have a rigidbody, and you're moving the platform using the transform. I would suggest re-evaluating your setup regarding collisions and consult the [Physics Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

Comment: In my second example I removed the trigger enter/exit in the moving platform. I now only have the trigger stay in the `Player` component.